# How to test and verify that Timber log been executed?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, junit4, robolectric

I have a function that has a Timber log call. So I need to verify in test that that log been called

```
Timber.tag("MyGag").d("My message $parameter")
```

Is there a way to verify that this log been executed?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways in which you can verify that:

A good solution which is well described in [this article](https://kotlintesting.com/test-timber/) is to create a "Spy" Timber tree, as follows:

First, we create a `TestTree` that holds and allows querying the logs. (It's a good idea to create this class in a `test` source dir to avoid it from being accessed in prod):

```
import timber.log.Timber

class TestTree : Timber.Tree() {
  val logs = mutableListOf<Log>()

  override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, t: Throwable?) {
    logs.add(Log(priority, tag, message, t))
  }

  data class Log(val priority: Int, val tag: String?, val message: String, val t: Throwable?)
}
```

Then, in our test class we "plant" that tree into Timber and perform any assertions on the `testTree` directly:

```
fun test() {
  val testTree = TestTree()
  Timber.plant(testTree)
  
  subjectUnderTest.invoke()

  val actual = testTree.logs.last()
  val expected = TestTree.Log(
      priority = Log.ERROR,
      message = "expected logged message",
      tag = "expcted logged tag,
      t = ExpectedException()
  )
  assertEquals(expected, actual)

}
```

Another way that you'll find a lot around (even though probably not the best one, also treated in the above article) is to use one of the usual mocking libs to mock the calls to the `Timber` object. That would looks something like this (assuming [mockk](https://mockk.io/) as mocking library, quite the same is valid with mockito with PowerMock and so on)

```
fun test() {
  // We're mocking statically, which is suboptimal
  mockStatic(Timber::class)
  
  sut.invoke()

  verify { Timber.d("Expected log message") }
}
```